# What's the difference between Application.Run() and Form.ShowDialog()?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application I want to show a login form first and then the main form if the login has been successful. Currently I'm doing it something like this:

```
var A = new LoginForm();
if ( A.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

But then I started wondering - what's the point of the `Application.Run()`? Why not just do `(new MainForm()).ShowDialog()` as well? What's the difference? And what would be the correct way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`Application.Run(Form)` starts a message loop on the current thread and displays the specified form. The message loop enables the form to receive Windows messages (eg, key presses, mouse clicks, paint invalidations) to allow it to appear responsive and have interaction with the user. When you call `ShowDialog()` on a `Form` instance, it actually does a similar thing and creates a modal message loop for the form on which `ShowDialog` has been called.

There is not much difference between the two calls. `Application.Run` does add some extra event handling enabling you to do some tidying up of resources when the main form is closed (see [Application.ThreadExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexit.aspx)).

The recommended way to start WinForms applications is using `Application.Run`, but I suspect this is more of a convention than a rule. The biggest reason to use `Application.Run` is if you want to open multiple non-modal forms. You can do this using:

```
new Form().Show();
new Form().Show();
Application.Run();
```

You could not achieve this using the `ShowDialog()` method as one of the forms would have to be modal.

---

As for your question of how to show a login form and then the main form if the login is successful, I think what you have is fine:

```
if (new LoginForm().ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

The alternative is to do the plumbing yourself and open an instance of `MainForm` in the closing event of the `LoginForm` if the login was successful.

Comment: So, this means you can have a message loop on the same thread as the two forms while being able to handle the three separately?

Comment: @SomeNickName With `new Form().Show; new Form2().Show(); Application.Run();`, you’d be initializing 2 forms and running 1 message loop which services 2 forms. There aren’t really 3 things of a kind to manage independently. So if one of your forms performs an operation on the GUI thread which freezes the processes, the other form will be marked “(Not Responding)” along with it because they share the same message loop. If you want them to actually be independent, you should run a separate process for each form.

Answer (score 6):

From my testing, I noticed this main difference:

When Application.Run is used, the form's Close button (red X) returns DialogResult.None; however, when ShowDialog is used, the Close button produces DialogResult.Cancel.

Does this matter to you? In my code, I was testing for DialogResult.Cancel to determine the exit code of my application. That was broken when the red X was used to close the form. I now test for DialogResult.OK to indicate a successful exit.

```
        return myForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: This is becouse Application.Run uses the Form.Show()

Answer (score 5):

From MSDN:

> This method adds an event handler to
>   the mainForm parameter for the Closed
>   event. The event handler calls
>   ExitThread to clean up the
>   application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx

Comment: Is that the only noteworthy difference? I checked with the Reflector and it seems that there is a lot more going on behind the scenes depending on which one was called. There are definitely some more subtle differences, although I cannot say what - the reflected code is pretty cryptic.

Comment: I just found one crazy one, and I arrived here while googling to see if anyone could explain why: I spent like an hour at work today trying to figure out why this.Hide(), and this.Visible = false, on my form, both actually closed the form rather than hid it. I was totally baffled. Apparently there's some difference - entirely reproduceable! - where form.ShowDialog() does this, but Application.Run() does the expected thing. What is up with that? (I guess the idea is, because it's modal, if it ever isn't displayed, it's assumed you want to close it.)

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation of the overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run#system-windows-forms-application-run(system-windows-forms-applicationcontext))

```
public static void Run(
    ApplicationContext context );
```

has a neat example with a different approach that involves two forms as well.

Comment: Good tip. Unfortunately it did not help me as I use WinCE.

Answer (score 2):

`Application.Run()` is for the start of application while `MainForm` is part of the application and `MainForm()).ShowDialog()` used to display it only.

`Application.Run()` is the `entry point` for your Application. same as `Main()` method is for some class or `ApplicationStart()` for a WebApplication

[**Application.Run()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx) has different overloads, one of which is without parameters. That Method starts application without an initial form.

Comment: So what does all that mean in terms of which one I should choose? So far it seems to me that both ways work just fine. But there must be some subtle differences, right?

Answer (score 2):

One key difference is that ShowDialog is usually a modal Dialog. If you wanted to create a user-friendly toolset, you would not want it to be comprised of modal dialog boxes.

Also, Application.Run() accepts more than just a form. It has a few overloads.

As for your application, I do not think it matters much. Application.Run makes sense to me because it denotes the start of your actual Application.

Comment: Since it is my main form, it does not matter if it's a Modal Dialog, no?

Answer (score 2):

For a more concerete example of a difference:

If your main form is an MDI form, then the behavior on clicking the close button (the 'x' in the upper right, or Alt-F4) is different depending on which method you use to show the form.

With `Application.Run(mainForm)`, the closing event of the child forms run, then the main form's closing event runs.

With `mainForm.ShowDialog`, the closing event of the main form runs, and the closing event of the child forms do not run.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing I notice that using Application.Run buttons with DialogResult does not close the form (OnFormClosing is not hit) compare to ShowDialog in which the buttons with DialogResult hit OnFormClosing and the close the form.