# c# windows form app

Tags: c#

I have created 2 windows form applications in a c# program. I did this:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

The second form is not loading.Why? how can i resolve this problem? i would like to activate both these forms in the same time. Each of this form application loades a different method. I would like to somehow create a paralel process for each of these forms.

solution and problem:
i've created 2 threads - for the 2 forms. This forms call the parent form. The thing is that the parent form has a vector in which i would like to continuously add elements from the form. I've noticed that the vector is reinitialized every time the thread is reactivated. how to change this thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Application.Run is blocking. It's running the application on the current thread. You'd have to start 2 separate threads with one of the Application.Run commands in each of them.

The best course of action would be to open one of the two in a separate thread.

Comment: i've created 2 threads - for the 2 formsl. This forms call the parent form. The thing is that the paretn form has a vector in which i would like to continuusly add elements from the form. I've noticed that the vector is reinitialized every time the thread is reactivated. how to chnage this thing?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a lot of experience with inter-thread communication.

Answer (score 4):

`Application.Run` is used to start your application and indicate which window should be loaded on application start (i.e. which window should be the main window). To display second form you need to create it and show it by hand, not using `Application.Run`.

```
var form = new Form2();
form.Show();
```

This code can be placed in Form1's constructor or in response to some event. It may not be created in the same method, where you call `Application.Run`, because this method will not run further, until you will close Form1 window. Probably Forms1's constructor is best place to do this.

Comment: Beat me to it, also see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

This will invoke Form1 and it will be waiting till this form is closed. After that the second Run method will be invoked.

Application.Run is synchronous method,

Answer (score 1):

See [adrianbanks' answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314514/whats-the-difference-between-application-run-and-form-showdialog):

The recommended way to start WinForms applications is using Application.Run, but I suspect this is more of a convention than a rule. The biggest reason to use Application.Run is if you want to open multiple non-modal forms. You can do this using:

```
new Form().Show();
new Form().Show();
Application.Run();
```

Comment: You forgot mention that in this case application process would not terminate if all forms will be closed, but its really usefull way

Answer (score 0):

I'm really can't understand what you are trying to accomplish, but close first form and the second will displayed :-)

You didnt see the second one because of Run method it didnt return control till you close working object at your case this is Forms1