# Does System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(form); require form.Dispose()?

Tags: winforms

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw58wzka.aspx)

> Dispose will be called automatically if the form is shown using the
>   Show method. If another method such as ShowDialog is used, or the form
>   is never shown at all, you must call Dispose yourself within your
>   application.

What happens if I launch a form via

`System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(form);`?

Closing the form allows execution to continue.  If I call form.ShowDialogue() after the block it throws up an `ObjectDisposedException`.  To be sure, do I need to call `form.Dispose()` when launching a form via `Application.Run()` or is there any advantage or disadvantage to doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ApplicationContext class controls the lifetime of the UI thread.  Its ExitThread() method initiates a shutdown that exits the internal message loop.  When you use the Application.Run(Form) overload then Winforms creates an ApplicationContext with the ApplicationContext(Form) constructor.  Which subscribes the form's HandleDestroyed event, the event handler calls ExitThread().

So the lifetime is purely based on whether the native Windows window for the form is alive.  The two common ways to destroy that window is the user clicking the window's Close button or your app calling the Close or Dispose methods.  Either way, the form is automatically disposed.  The form object is dead after this, trying to revive it throws ODE.

Comment: I have some legacy code that launches forms within the application code with `Application.Run(form)`.  To me that seems really oddball.  Why do this instead of `form.ShowDialogue()`?

Comment: NM found a good post on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314514/whats-the-difference-between-application-run-and-form-showdialog

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after posting I found the answer in another area of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx)

> The Dispose method of the Form class will be called prior to the
>   return of this method.