# C# dynamic label blank

Tags: c#

I created a very basic console app that executes some code behind the scenes. While it's doing this, it generates a custom message box (it's technically a Windows Form) that just displays one label telling the user to please wait. The issue is that the label NEVER is displayed (it's just a big white box where the label should be). I tried creating a dynamic label and putting it there, but this too does not work.

The form is shown in the following manner:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
   MyForm form = new MyForm();
   form.Show();
   try {
   // Execute other logic
   } finally { form.Close(); }
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with calling Show(), but I'm not positive. I put in logging and see that it's going through the constructor, generating the dynamic label (which is added to the form via Controls.Add(myLabel)), but it still does not show any label.

Comment: Are you blocking the UI thread while this is happening? That's my guess.

Comment: might I ask what your `MyForm` class looks like?

Comment: @JonSkeet He's doing this in a console app - I don't think there is a "UI thread" :)

Comment: @ReedCopsey: I'd missed that. Not sure *what* happens if you call Show when you don't have a UI thread...

Comment: @JonSkeet Nothing (visual) happens - it "posts" messages, but they never get processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Form` requires the message pump to be started in order to display correctly.  This requires calling [Application.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx).  Unfortunately, this will block the current thread until the "application" is complete, so won't be able to just "drop in" to your code.

That being said, if you're developing an application which requires windows, you should consider making it a true windows application instead of a console application.  You could just hide the main form, if required, and that will allow code like yours above to work properly.

Comment: It's actually supposed to be part of the installation of a different product. The form I'm trying to display is a "Please wait..." message box, so it's not a true windows application

Comment: @Sean If you're displaying messages, you should make it a windows application.  The main form can be hidden and do all of the processing.

Comment: in the properties for the project it is set to Windows Application (my hacky way of getting the console to not appear), your suggestion is that I just add a main form that's not visible, so that the messages from this other form are processed?

Comment: @Sean Yes - You need to call `Application.Run` if you want to use non-modal windows, so there is a message pump running for the app.

Comment: could I make a function in that class then that calls Application.Run just for the duration of that class?

Comment: @Sean Application.Run is a blocking call - it'll block your thread, so you'd have to do it on a separate thread if you did that.

Comment: Ok thanks for making me more aware about Application.Run(), I was able to find what I needed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314514/whats-the-difference-between-application-run-and-form-showdialog