# Difference between Application.Run() and ShowDialog()?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I'm working on a simple Winform app as a first stab at using the MVP pattern. I'm used to the standard, auto-generated code for starting up a form, which is `Application.Run(new Form1());` The MVP sample projects I'm looking at do a lot more in `Program.cs`, but the basic part is something like this:

```
TestView view = new TestView();
TestPresenter presenter = new TestPresenter(view);
presenter.LoadView();
view.ShowDialog();
```

As I understand it, the `ShowDialog` method is similar to `Application.Run` in that it creates a message loop for the object, so it should function the same as a form started with `Run`.

My question is: Is there a notable difference between `Application.Run()` and `Show.Dialog()` that would determine using one over the other in this situation? As far as I can tell from the test apps nothing runs differently, but I know that that doesn't mean much when it comes to software.

Comment: looks like [this was asked already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314514/whats-the-difference-between-application-run-and-form-showdialog)

Comment: @Jonesy: Oh my god, I swear I searched for nearly that exact phrasing and got nothing ><

Comment: With over 500k questions with the C# tag, pretty much everything is a duplicate now.

Comment: I find it especially odd that the other question didn't show up in the little drop-down as I typed my title. One of the answers in the other question gave me what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Run` is used to stat the *first* form.  After the first form you should use `Form.Show()` or `Form.ShowDialog()`  The main difference between the two is that `ShowDialog()` starts the form modally, meaning you can't switch to other forms until that form is closed (similar to a `MessageBox`)

Comment: You can use ShowDialog for the first form too. OP wanted to know what's the difference in this case, not for following forms.