# .NET CE 3.5 WinForm Hiding main form right after Application.Run();

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5

I found an answer that shows a nice technique to use in order to accomplish this, but the answer was from 2008 and it doesn't appear to be valid today?

It recommended to remove the parameter from `Application.Run()` in order to manually show/hide form as required. But in `.NET Compact Edition 3.5`, parameter must be provided.

I have the following code with no luck, form still displays. **I wish to hide the main form upon the program starting.**

```
static class Program
{
    public static Form1 MainForm = new Form1();
    [MTAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(MainForm);
        MainForm.Visible = false;
        MainForm.Hide(); //Also tried this...
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement a splash screen?

Comment: Nope. Just displaying the form, only when required. The application will autostart when phone turns on; Windows Mobile CE 6.5 Pro.

Comment: Your best bet would be to implement an application context to act as a medium between your application and the system. That way your application can still run, and you can manage the UI state of the Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [don't have to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2314514/1997232) use `Application.Run()` (with or w/o parameter):

```
static class Program
{
    private static Form1 _mainForm = new Form1();
    public static Form1 MainForm { get { return _mainForm; } }

    [MTAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // blablabla

        // do not call this until you want to show main window
        MainForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Obvious approach! Didn't think it was this easy ;) thank you.